# Проблема по геометрии, олимпиадный уровень

Tags: математика, геометрия

> Через центр O окружности Оmega, описанной около треугольника ABC, проведена прямая, параллельная BC и пересекающая стороны AB и AC точках B1 и C1 соответственно. Окружность omega проходит через точки B1, C1 и касается Оmega в точке k. Найдите радиус окружности Оmega, если B1C1 = 6, AK = 6, а расстояние между прямыми BC и B1C1 равно 2 . В ответ запишите квадрат радиуса. *(Omega и omega - разные окружности)*

Как адекватно сделать построение?

Comment: Чертеж, во → https://i.gyazo.com/5bb50772aa96dd32980ad3c1c420dab1.png , так сходу не приходит решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Картинка с подсказкой где же на самом деле точка K

[image: чертеж]

Comment: А можно ли как-то это обосновать?

Comment: Не понятно, кстати, какую роль играет внутренняя окружность. На всех приведенных чертежах, на глаз кажется её центр находится на 'OK'... может это можно доказать и как-то использовать.

Comment: @Optimus ну поскольку окружности касаются друг друга, то довольно логично что их центры и точка касания лежат на одной прямой

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME см выше

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот вам вариант построения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Omega - черная, и omega - оранжевая

Comment: Увы, очень уж "не общая" картина получается - окружность *касается* сторон треугольника, например, треугольник - равносторонний... А прямые BC и B1C1 как раз не параллельны. Это все сбивает с толку и подсознательно наводит на неверные рассуждения.